# VSTS change agent state from offline to online after installing it

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, agent

i'm facing a problem with VSTS agent state is offline i installed the agent through cmd under the right pool and downloaded after that but it still offline any help please ?

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Comment: Yes,  it will have to run as service in order to work well and the cmd has to be as administrator !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the build agent is running as interactive mode, you need to start agent by running **run.cmd** file:

1. Open Command line as administrator
2. Run **run.cmd** file (under agent folder)

If the build agent is running as service, you can check whether the related service is running in Services.

Comment: Thank you indeed !!